# Find unique superdirectories in a set of Java File objects

Tags: java, file

Given an unordered set of Java `File` objects, I want to eliminate all those that are subdirectories (or files in subdirectories) of other `Files` in the set. For instance, given:

```
File("/john/paul/george/ringo")
File("/foo/bar/baz")
File("/foo/bar/elvis")
File("/john/paul")
File("/john/jacob")
File("/foo/bar/baz/qux/quux")
File("/john/")
File("/foo/bar/")
```

the set should reduce to:

```
File("/foo/bar/")
File("/john/")
```

I can imagine cobbling something together based on converting to Strings with `File.getAbsolutePath()` and sorting (possibly by length first, then lexicographically), but surely this is a solved problem, or at least somebody must already have written utility methods for things like determining whether one `File` is an ancestor of another.

Comment: You could probably build something off of http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html, specifically `directoryContains`, but ultimately you'll still need to do a trivial amount of work.

Comment: You may find [File.toPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toPath--) and [Path.startsWith](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#startsWith-java.nio.file.Path-) useful.  java.io.File has been obsolete since 2011, like Vector and Hashtable;  like them, it is still needed for legacy APIs but shouldn't be used unless necessary.

Comment: @VGR Unfortunately I'm stuck with Java 6 for this project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the best of programmers, but here's my shot at it. There's quite a bit of recursion involved.

```
class UniqueDirectories {
    private final Map<String, UniqueDirectories> directories = new HashMap<String, UniqueDirectories>();
    private boolean locked = false;

    public UniqueDirectories() {}

    private UniqueDirectories(boolean locked) {
        this.locked = locked;
    }

    public boolean add(String path) {
        if (path == null)
            return false;
        if (path.isEmpty())
            return false;
        if (locked)
            return false;

        String[] tokens = path.split("(?<!^)[/\\\\]", 2);
        UniqueDirectories existingDirectory = directories.get(tokens[0]);

        if (existingDirectory == null) {
            if (tokens.length < 2 || tokens[1].isEmpty()) {
                directories.put(tokens[0], new UniqueDirectories(true));

                return true;
            } else {
                UniqueDirectories newDirectory = new UniqueDirectories(false);
                directories.put(tokens[0], newDirectory);

                return newDirectory.add(tokens[1]);
            }
        } else if (tokens.length >= 2 && !tokens[1].isEmpty()) {
            return existingDirectory.add(tokens[1]);
        } else {
            directories.put(tokens[0], new UniqueDirectories(true));

            return true;
        }
    }

    public List<String> toList(char delimiter) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, UniqueDirectories> entry : directories.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().directories.size() == 0) {
                list.add(entry.getKey());
            } else {
                for (String subdirectory : entry.getValue().toList(delimiter)) {
                    list.add(entry.getKey() + delimiter + subdirectory);
                }
            }
        }

        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] testPaths = {
                "/john/paul/george/ringo",
                "/foo/bar/baz",
                "/foo/bar/elvis",
                "/john/paul",
                "/john/jacob",
                "/foo/bar/baz/qux/quux",
                "/john/",
                "/foo/bar/"
        };

        UniqueDirectories directories = new UniqueDirectories();

        for (String path : testPaths) {
            directories.add(path);
        }

        System.out.println(directories.toList('/'));
    }
}
```

Sorry about the lack of comments. Too lazy to go back and do it, but at least the code's relatively short. I haven't put it through rigorous testing either (just used the ones you provided), so you may want to use some more test cases.

The biggest thing to be careful with is consistency. If you start a path with a delimiter, all paths should start with one. Conversely, if one path does not start with a delimiter, the rest shouldn't either. Otherwise, they will be treated as different paths. You could easily fix this by removing the lookbehind in the regex though; I just wasn't sure how you wanted it to behave.